# Configurable product on sale have an error on variation price

Tags: configurable-product, price, special-price, price-rules, associate-products

When I change product variation on the dropdown, the full price of that product is not loaded, it continues to show the price of the default configurable product. I do not know why this error happens and even with the standard Magento files, this error occurs.

***`It's ok`***
[image]

***`Don't work`***
[image]

***`Price that should show`***

[image]